# Matlab Classification Tree generation with non-numeric observations

Tags: matlab, classification

I am trying to generate a classification tree in Matlab using `ClassificationTree.fit()` or `classregtree()`. My data is non-numeric however, I cannot find a command which will generate a classification from non-numeric data.

So my question is how do I generate a classification tree from non-numeric data?

Comment: what kind of data do you have? And can you map what you have to a numeric form?

Comment: I ended up using Weka which has the ability to use categorical data. There are functions like `nominal` to create a numeric mapping from categorical string data but those weren't producing proper trees.